# onPlayStatus as3

Tags: actionscript-3

New to this one. Have this code for viewing multiple netstream events. Want to use the onPlayStatus to loop the "flv/intro.flv" and for the rest of the videos, I would like them to return to the intro.flv after they are done playing, but I can't find anything that helps enough. Can anyone offer a link or some help with the function? Here is my code so far :

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

var metaDataListener:Object = new Object();
metaDataListener.onMetaData = function(meta:Object){
}

ns.client = metaDataListener
var myVideo:Video = new Video(800, 600);
myVideo.x = 0;
myVideo.y = 0;
addChild(myVideo);
setChildIndex(myVideo, 0);
myVideo.attachNetStream(ns);
ns.play("flv/intro.flv");

duetBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo1);
vantageBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo2);
cabrioBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo3);
classicBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo4);
laundryBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo5);
resourceBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo6);
industryBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo7);
homeBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo8);
function playVideo1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ns.play ("flv/duet.flv");
}    
function playVideo2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ns.play("flv/vantage.flv");
}
function playVideo3(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ns.play("flv/cabrio.flv");
}
function playVideo4(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ns.play("flv/classic.flv");
}



function playVideo5(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ns.play("flv/laundry.flv");
}
function playVideo6(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ns.play("flv/resource.flv");
}
function playVideo7(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ns.play("flv/industry.flv");
}
function playVideo8(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ns.play ("flv/intro.flv");
}
```

Comment: You can attach an event listener to the NetStream object that detects when a video has finished playing, although the implementation is different to a normal event listener: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#event:onPlayStatus

Comment: Yea I knew that thanks. That's what I said in the question. I'm just looking for a little more help. Maybe an example of how it's done. The doc onPlayStatus doesn't give anything more.

Comment: Ok I used this code below to loop the video. Works fine for the loop of the intro and now I just need a if statement to tell the others to go to intro instead of looping, but if all videos end with Netstream.play.stop, how do I distinguish the videos?    var count:Number = 0;  ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ns_onPlayStatus);  function ns_onPlayStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void {   trace(event.info.code);  if (event.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {  if(count == 0){  ns.play("flv/intro.flv");  count++;  } else {  ns.seek(0);  }  }  }

Comment: Sounds like you've changed your question.

Comment: Should I post in another forum? This has to do with the same question. Is there an answer or am I being rude not posting this in a new thread? I figured a way to loop the video, just would like further help please.

Comment: The code I posted can be applied to each of your button `MouseEvent` functions. So every time a button is pressed, the video plays, and then when it's done it will play the intro. Let me change the code to include playing the `intro.flv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach an event listener to the NetStream object that detects when a video has finished playing.

```
var introPlayer:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); // nc refers to shared net connection declared earlier
var introVid:Video = new Video(800, 600);
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, checkStreamStatus);

function checkStreamStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void {
        switch (e.info.code) {
              case "NetStream.Play.Complete":
              playIntro();
              break;
        }
};

function playIntro():void {
       addChild(introVid);
       introVid.attachNetStream(introPlayer);
       introPlayer.play("flv/intro.flv");
}
```

Have changed the code completely to match the set-up you were using originally. This is how you're supposed to do it, apologies for previous answer. This is the correct way of doing it though.

Comment: I think this seems to conflict with the first ns.play("flv/intro.flv") code because it gives the error Access of possibly undefined property onPlayStatus through a reference with static type flash.net:NetStream that refers to my last function playVideo8. Sorry just try to get a full understanding.

Comment: Try declaring the separate `NetStream` and `Video` objects outside the function as I have edited above. Hopefully this will work. If not, please paste the error message as you see it exactly.

Comment: Yea same. Here are the errors - Symbol 'container', Layer 'nav', Frame 1, Line 37 1119: Access of possibly undefined property onPlayStatus through a reference with static type flash.net:NetStream and Symbol 'container', Layer 'nav', Frame 1, Line 39 1119: Access of possibly undefined property Play through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: Ok I've changed it all for you. Let me know how it goes! :)

Comment: Ok question? First you had this code inside of the playVideo function and now this is different. I added this inside the playVideo function. I get no error but nothing loops. Is this replacing my initial netstream variable or is this placed somewhere after?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that you might have to change what you already did by deleting stuff. `introPlayer` is a variable I thought to introduce to keep the `intro.flv` separate as it is shared amongst the other functions. It isn't necessary, you could just use `ns.play("flv/intro.flv");`

Comment: @AlexW let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1986/discussion-between-ichigo-and-alexw)

Comment: Sorry dude I'm actually quite busy. :) Keep hacking!

Comment: No problem. Its just the code doesn't do anything at all. Hopefully someone else can look at this and help. This is pretty annoying. I'll keep working with it.

Answer (score 3):

If `NetStream.Play.Complete` is not dispatched, replace it with:
`NetStream.Play.Stop` or `NetStream.Buffer.Flush`

Comment: or NetStream.Buffer.Empty